# Read Java Object in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, controller

I have a code like this :

```
  function () {
    var field=$('#bomPartModels').val(); 
    START.bom.addIcons({

        "ABC123-2":  {"name": "", "qty": 4, "image": "images/UK_OO_HR2000_IT.jpg", "incart": 0, "model": []},
        "ABC123-3":  {"name": "Downconverter Mixer", "qty": 16, "image": "images/UK_Universal_Cable_Adaptors_IT.jpg", "incart": 0, "model": []},
      });
  });
});
```

The bomPartModels is  a list of Java beans objects with each bean containing name ,qty image etc. This has been returned from controller adding to model

I need to replace the static values in START.bom.addIcons with the dynamic values reading from bomPartModels  object . How can i do this?

Comment: What does the value of `field` look like? Without knowing that it's difficult to really say.

Comment: The field contains list of bomPartModels. Each bomPartModel is a java  object with setters and getter for each variable of id,name,qty,image. So on the jsp i access the name as ${bomPartModels[0].name} i want to use the same name on the jquery with replacing the static  values which is  "ABC123-2":  {"name": "", "qty": 4, "image": "images/UK_OO_HR2000_IT.jpg", "incart": 0, "model": []},

Comment: And what does that list look like? The exact value taken from your page's source code or your browser's developer tools, not a description of it.

Comment: I have passed the list from Controller to jsp which contains list of bomPartModels. I read the value on jsp as  ${bomPartModels[0].id} , ${bomPartModels[0].name}, ${bomPartModels[0].qty} . How do i use the same object to replace static values of "ABC123-2":  {"name": "", "qty": 4, "image": "images/UK_OO_HR2000_IT.jpg", "incart": 0, "model": []},

Comment: Like I said, post the **actual value** not a description of what it is or where it comes from. You do `var field=$('#bomPartModels').val();`, *what is the value of `field` after that line executes?*

Comment: alert(field) returs [BomPartModel (8799828607075), BomPartModel (8799828639843)

Comment: Ok, is the "ABC123-1" part the `id` field of your `BomPartModel` object in Java?

Comment: Yes ABC123-1 is the id of BomPartModel

Comment: need some help on this urgently

Answer (score 0):

You can use  jQuery extend function to replace value from your default object by the on contained in your received object.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

```
fullobject = $.extend({}, static_object, dynamic_object));
```

Comment: Thanks baart my problem is the value 'field' contains list of java bean object(bomPartModels1,bomPartModels2) which has setters and getters for the variables id,name,qty,image. So on the jsp level i usually read the value as  ${bomPartModels[0].id} ,  ${bomPartModels[0].name}, ${bomPartModels[0].qty} but how to do this  in the above scenario  i.e replacing the static values "ABC123-2":  {"name": "", "qty": 4, "image": "images/UK_OO_HR2000_IT.jpg", "incart": 0, "model": []},

Comment: Your question lacks full explanations.
As far as I understand :
 - store your static value in a javascript object.
 - store the answer from your server in another object (a var).
 - merge the 2 with the extend method shown above.
 - use the result for your needs

This should do what you expect (at least, it does what I understood you expect)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want to do is generate the correct JSON representation of that JavaScript object in your JSP page in the place of the static object literal you have now. So in the JSP that section of code would look like this:

```
function () {
    var field=$('#bomPartModels').val(); 
    START.bom.addIcons(
        // code to generate JSON here
    );
});
```

The `// code to generate JSON here` part is where it gets interesting. There are a number of ways you could do this, but what you don't want to be doing is trying to generate it by hand; that's just asking for errors to be introduced and for it to end up going wrong.

Personally, whenever I need to generate JSON content in a JSP, I use the [json-taglib](http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/). That would look something like this:

```
START.bom.addIcons(<json:object>
    <c:forEach items="${bomPartModels}" var="bpm">
        <json:object name="${bpm.id}">
            <json:property name="name" value="${bpm.name}"/>
            <json:property name="qty" value="${bpm.qty}"/>
            ... // other properties
        </json:object>
    </c:forEach>
</json:object>);
```

The downside to that is that you're restricted to having your JavaScript code inside of the JSP so that it works.